# Should you choose highly owned or little owned players in fantasy sport

Tags: probability, statistics, game-theory

Here's the situation:

It's a fantasy soccer game where players score points for my team based on their actual performances on the pitch.

I have a team of 11 players and their is no limit to the number of teams that can select a player. All the teams exist in the same league in the game.

I have 10 picked and need to pick between two similar candidates for the final spot, both play for the same team, both have fairly similar expectations in terms of points scored over the season.

Player A has been selected by almost 60% of the players (3,000,000+)

Player B has been selected by about 15% of the players.

My questions concerns the situation where my pick scores fewer points over, say, 10 weeks.

Suppose that one of these players scores 100 points and the other scores 90 points over this period.  If I have picked the 'loser' then my team has 10 points less than it could have.  This is true whichever player that happens to be.

It seems intuitive to me, however, that my team will be relatively 'better off' if I pick Player A (and he is the loser) than if I pick player B (and he is the loser).

I have arrived at the conclusion that if I pick the less popular player, the rest of my team (i.e the other 10 players) would have to contribute more points to my overall total in order for my team to maintain the same relative rank.

Am I correct?  I am trying to explain why I think this to someone and getting nowhere - I can't even really convince myself!  They insist it makes no difference.  Maybe they are correct.

Hopefully someone can help a novice, Im not even sure what tags to give this...

Thanks

Comment: This question seems to assume that the reader already know what the rules of whatever game it is you're playing are. Unless you explain the relevant rules in the question, it is not a mathematical question, but merely a guessing game about what the heck you mean by "better off", "rest of my team", "contribute more points" and so forth.

Comment: I'll do an edit.

Comment: At first glance, ownership statistics are a good signal of how good a player is. That seems indisputable so long as you accept that people aren't totally uninformed when picking up players. Still, these numbers aren't perfect signals. Many teams are basically inactive past the draft, so you might see injured or suspended players still on a lot of rosters.

Comment: Yes, I get that.  It's not about which player I should pick because of how good or bad the player is.  But which player should i pick based purely on the ownership stats.  Or does it really make no difference.

Comment: Well if you pick up A, it's unlikely that B gets picked up by anyone else. Then in your 100 vs 90 point scenario, it might have been better to have owned A. That is because, given A scores 90 and B 100, it is more likely that B scored his 100 points as a free agent, therefore helping no opponents. That is an advantage. In the reverse case, it is more likely that those 100 points helped a competitor.

Comment: Yes, that helps.  I'm not too sure if things like free-agent apply - I'm in the UK and perhaps should have said Fantasy Soccer, not Fantasy Football... There is no limit on the number of teams that can select a player and in theory a popular pick could be chosen by 100% of teams.  I don't know if this is different in US fantasy sports?

Comment: Ah yes, in the fantasy (American) football, there are leagues of ten or so teams, each of which maintain disjoint rosters. Only so many players can be owned by each team and the remaining players are free agents. So that adds the element of competition I described above. Without that, it's not immediate to me why player A would be better, but I could be missing something else.

Comment: If there was only one player per team and if i picked the loser, picking player A means there are 450,000 teams above me, but picking player B means there are 1,800,000 teams above me.  Add in the rest of the team, and my combination of 10 players needs to score better than a lot more teams to keep me in the same relative position.

Comment: Oh, that makes sense. I think I agree with you now that I grasp how your league works.

Answer (score 0):

Who are you competing with and what is your objective?  It seems there are $5,000,000$ people who have picked teams.  Are you ranked against all of them, or only some local group?  If against the whole $5,000,000$ you are unlikely to win outright. Do you want to come in the top so many percent?

Basically you can think of the two players as having the same expectation, but B has a higher variance in your ranking against other teams.  If you are in a local competition and want the best chance to win outright, variance is good.  If B beats A you are ahead of a lot of people.  If your happiness is linear in finishing place, you are more concerned with expectation and it doesn't matter who you take.

Comment: I added a bit to the question when it became apparent that US and UK fantasy football is not the same thing...

Comment: There are mini leagues but overall rank amongst all the 3,000,000+ entrants is the question here